# How do I compare elements of one array to a column of a matrix, then shorten the matrix correspondingly?

Tags: matlab, matrix, comparison, data-analysis, logical-operators

I have a matrix 'Z' sized 100000x2 and imported as an Excel file using readmatrix. I have a created array 'Time' (Time = [-200:0.1:300]'). I would like to compare all values in column 1 of 'Z' to 'Time' and eliminate all values of column 1 of 'Z' that do not equal a value of 'Time', thus shortening my 'Z' matrix to match my desired time values. Column 2 are pressure traces, so this would give me my desired time values and the corresponding pressure trace.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of thing can be done without loops:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,1,1,2,3,4]; 
x = [x', (x+1)'] % this is your 'Z' data from the excel file (toy example here)
x =

     1     2
     2     3
     3     4
     4     5
     1     2
     1     2
     2     3
     3     4
     4     5
y = [1,2]; % this is your row of times you want eliminated
z = x(:,1)==y % create a matrix logical arrays indicating the matches in the first column
z =

  9×2 logical array

   1   0
   0   1
   0   0
   0   0
   1   0
   1   0
   0   1
   0   0
   0   0
z = z(:,1)+z(:,2); % there is probably another summing technique that is better for your case
b = [x(z~=1,1), x(z~=1,2)] % use matrix operations to extract the desired rows
b =

     3     4
     4     5
     3     4
     4     5
```

All the entries of `x` where the first column did not equal 1 or 2 are now gone.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = ismember(Z(:,1),Time); % logical indexes of the rows you want to keep
Z(~x,:) = []; % get rid of the other rows
```

Or instead of shortening Z you could create a new array to use downstream in your code:

```
x = ismember(Z(:,1),Time); % logical indexes of the rows you want to keep
Znew = Z(x,:); % the subset you want
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to loop over all rows, use a nested if statement to check the item, and delete the row if it doesn't match.

Syntax for loops:

```
for n = 1:100000:
    //(operation)//
end
```

Syntax for if statements:

```
if x == y
    //(operation)//
```

Syntax for deleting a row: `Z(rownum,:) = [];`

Comment: It is much much simpler and more computationally efficient to use logical operands to do this. See my answer below.